# Lookup in shell script

Tags: linux, unix, join, lookup

I have two files as below:

**cat file_1:**

```
12 a

34 b

24 c

18 d
```

**cat file_2:**

```
x a

y c

z d
```

I want something  like in shell script:

```
x a 12

y c 24

z d 18
```

File 1 and file 2 has different number of rows and join is not working as I can't sort the files (the files are already sorted for the requirement if I sort again for join then requirement will not served).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Maulik Patel: Try also.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{A[$2]=$0;next} ($2 in A){print A[$2] FS $1}'  Input_file2  Input_file1
```

Very short description: 
So here I am using FNR==NR condition which will be TRUE when Input_file is being read and saving $0(current line's value) in to array A whose index is field 2.

Then while reading 2nd Input_file I am checking which second field of Input_file2 is coming in array A and printing it's value with Input_file1's first field.

Comment: You don't need the entire line `$0`, as it is not optimal for larger number of fields, use only the fields required. Also your answer is an exact replication of mine in-terms of logic, you can very well remove it for the sake of duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it

```
join -1 2 -2 2 file_2 file_1 --nocheck-order -o 1.1,1.2,2.1

x a 12
y c 24
z d 18
```

Comment: this works 100% fine for my case (release 6.5 ) but the same is not working in unix 6.6

Comment: release 6.5? what is that?